# Want to add certain items from a list to a DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

**A brief intro**

The program runs a test on the machines. Then a dialogBox appears asking the user if all the machines worked correctly. If they say no another window appears with the dataGridView asking which machines failed through the checkBox method. This then sets the status to the ERROR status so the program can continue running while ignoring the machines with errors.

I have this class with the two properties

```
public class ASM
{
    public byte DeviceID
    public ASMStatus Status
}
```

I put this in a list

```
list<ASM001.ASM> ASMs = new list();
```

Now I want to add this list to a bindingSource in my dataGridView but only those whose Status equals `ASMStatus.IDLE`

I thought about just creating those that have idle into another list and attaching that to the binding list, however, the dataGridView also has a checkBox column that determines if the status needs to be changed to `ASMStatus.ERROR`

```
public partial class FailedMessageBox : Form
{
    public FailedMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        col1.HeaderText = "Device Failed";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);

    }

    private void FailedMessageBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Global.ASMs;
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that when the user clicks OK the current ASMs in the list get set to ERROR which is why I thought a bindinglist would work the best

I am wondering if there was a quick way to do this or if I just have to do a bunch of loops.

Comment: Would a simple `dataGridView1.DataSource = Global.ASMs.Where(a => a.Status == ASMStatus.IDLE);` do the trick?

Comment: That didn't work. I had tried it with Global.ASMs.Select(a => a.Status == ASMStatus.IDLE) also

Answer (score 0):

What about something similar in your Page_load:

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    // You could put a Where Clause here to limit the returns
    // i.e. context.ASMs.Where(s => s.Status == ASMStatus.IDLE).Load()
    context.ASMs.Load(); 
    var data = context.ASMs.Local.ToBindingList();

    var bs = new BindingSource();

    bs.DataSource = data;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

You should add a BindingSource directly to the page but I am just showing adding it in code. Then you can access it like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if ((bool) row.Cells["Device Failed"].Value == true)
    {
        var line = row.DataBoundItem();
        line.Status = ASMStatus.ERROR;
    }
}
```

Make sure you save the changes.